# How to use one module from another module in a Rust cargo project?

Tags: module, rust

There's a lot of Rust [documentation](https://www.google.ca/search?q=rust+use+module) about using modules, but I haven't found an example of a Cargo binary that has multiple modules, with one module using another. My example has three files inside the src folder. Modules a and b are at the same level. One is not a submodule of another.

main.rs:

```
mod a;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    a::a();
}
```

a.rs:

```
pub fn a() {
    println!("A");
    b::b();
}
```

and b.rs:

```
pub fn b() {
    println!("B");
}
```

I've tried variations of `use b` and `mod b` inside a.rs, but I cannot get this code to compile. If I try to use `use b`, for example, I get the following error:

```
 --> src/a.rs:1:5
  |
1 | use b;
  |     ^ no `b` in the root. Did you mean to use `a`?
```

What's the right way to have Rust recognize that I want to use module b from module a inside a cargo app?

Comment: Interesting, I thought I was the only one who did not understand that part in the docs. However, it was easy to know by experimenting with it.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You'll have to include `b.rs` somewhere, typically with `mod b;`. If `b` is a child of `a` (instead of being a sibling of `a`), there are two ways to do this:

- **Recommended**: rename `a.rs` into `a/mod.rs` and `b.rs` into `a/b.rs`. Then you can `mod b;` in `a/mod.rs`.
- Instead, you can just `#[path = "b.rs"] mod b;` in `a.rs` without renaming sources.

If `b` is intended to be a sibling of `a` (instead of being a child of `a`), you can just `mod b;` in `main.rs` and then `use crate::b;` in `a.rs`.

Comment: Thanks. That seems counterintuitive. I need to `mod b` in `main.rs` in order to `use b` in `a.rs`.

Comment: The idea is that `mod` is for building the module tree and `use` is for short-circuiting it. The absolute path `::b::b();` works without `use b;`. (Note that the syntax for absolute paths will change in future versions of Rust, in favor of [RFC 2126](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2126-path-clarity.md).)

Comment: @user8360684 Agreed

Answer (score 25):

The method from [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48071730/155423) doesn't work for me in Rust 1.33. Instead, I use the sibling module like this:

```
use crate::b;
```

Comment: Would it be possible to explain your answer in to the context? I am having trouble following your solution

Comment: I suppose this works only if you include b in the main.rs file with mod b.

Comment: This recipe fails with Rust 1.70.

Answer (score 4):

In the latest Rust 1.63, we can use [super](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-03-paths-for-referring-to-an-item-in-the-module-tree.html?highlight=super#starting-relative-paths-with-super) keyword to refer siblings

```
// main.rs
mod a;
mod b;

fn main() {
}

// a.rs
pub fn a() {
    println!("A");
    super::b::b();
}

// b.rs
pub fn b() {
    println!("B");
}
```