# Rust Import structure from another file

Tags: import, rust

Here's my file structure:

```
src
├── [2.4K]  game_of_life.rs
├── [1.7K]  main.rs
└── [1.9K]  preset.rs
```

File contents:
`preset.rs`:

```
pub struct Preset {
    ...
}

impl Preset {
    ...
}
```

## Error I got

I tried importing `Preset` in `main.rs`:

```
mod preset;
```

And it worked fine.

After that I tried to import `Preset` in `game_of_life.rs` using the same line of code, but got an error:

```
Error: file not found for module `preset`
Help: name the file either game_of_life/preset.rs or game_of_life/preset/mod.rs inside the directory "src"
```

I don't understand why Rust is trying to find the `preset` in `game_of_life`.

## What I tried to do to fix it

I found, that I have to wrap `Preset` in `pub mod preset`, but this didn't help me.

Comment: Hi there! I believe your question is answered by [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48071513/2408867). In short: the `mod` statements both go into `main.rs`. I.e. `mod preset; mod game_of_life;`. In `game_of_life.rs` you can then import `Preset` via `use crate::preset::Preset`. Remember: *first* build a module tree (no cycles!) with `mod` statements, *then* import names into scope via `use` (cycles allowed). Please let us know if this indeed answers your question, then we can mark this as duplicate.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt, Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I needed. Thanks for explanation too.

Answer (score 4):

I found an answer:
I just had to use `use crate::preset::Preset`. To understand how and why this works read the first comment under my question.