# 'use' keyword not working (calling from sibling file)

Tags: rust, module

I'm trying to `use` a struct from a `value.rs` file from `chunk.rs`, but it is not working. This is my current file hierarchy.

```
src
|
|---value.rs
|---chunk.rs
|---other files
```

Here is my `value.rs` code:

```
pub enum Value {
}

pub struct ValueArray {
    values: Vec<Value>,
}

pub impl Value {
    pub fn new() -> Value {
        Value {
            values: Vec::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn write_chunk(&mut self, value: Value) {
        self.code.push(value);
    }
}
```

Here is my `chunk.rs` code:

```
use crate::value::ValueArray; // Error Here

pub enum OpCode {
    OpReturn,
}

pub struct Chunk {
    pub code: Vec<OpCode>,
    constants: value::ValueArray,
}

impl Chunk {
    pub fn new() -> Chunk {
        Chunk {
            code: Vec::new(),
            constants: value::ValueArray::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn write_chunk(&mut self, byte: OpCode) {
        self.code.push(byte);
    }
}
```

This is my exact error message:

```
unresolved import `crate::value`
could not find `value` in the crate rootrustc(E0432)
chunk.rs(1, 12): could not find `value` in the crate root
```

I'm not sure why it isn't working since I've done something very similar in another sibling file. I'm new to Rust, so I appreciate all of your help. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use one module from another module in a Rust cargo project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48071513/how-to-use-one-module-from-another-module-in-a-rust-cargo-project)

Comment: Yes, this helps me with additional information. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax I'm using to include a file ("lib.rs") with naked structs/functions (no explicit module defined) is:

```
mod lib;
use crate::lib::*;
```

So you must be missing `mod value;`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define the `value` module on the `lib.rs` file

```
pub mod value;
```